# How can we implement a CurveMapping widget in a script using python api?

Tags: python, interface

How do we implement a CurveMapping widget (similar to RGB curves) in our own scripts using the python API to remap a range of values?

Comment: I read all those answers. But, I couldn't get to know how to change the curve and evaluate values from it. Currently, I could get a CurveMapping widget to draw in the undo panel, but can't actually make use of it.

Comment: I get a context error that I am not allowed to write data to a CurveMap from the 3d view.

Comment: Suggest always mention what you *read* already in your question. Also add your code to the question... Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask